# AsyncTask exception RuntimeException

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-asynctask

I'm trying to connect to mysql using AsyncTask in android but i am having complications. I'm using an interface to return data from AsyncTask, but when i run the code I get the following error: exception RuntimeException. Thank you very much to all.

Comment: please post the full exception message and the stack trace

Comment: Does the error occur if you comment out `//listener.onTaskCompleted(listaNegocios);` in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: As I have checked with logs, the problem is in the parsing, just in int lat = (Integer.parseInt(latitud)*1000000), but i dont know how to fix it

Comment: What values do you have for `lat` and `lon` if you add `Log.e("lat: ", lat);` and `Log.e("lon: ", lon);`

Comment: Log.e I can not use that because it must be of the form Log.e (String, String)

Comment: Passing an int to Log.e will automatically resolve to the toString() method of int... If you like, use `Log.e("lat: ", lat.toString()); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a general Exception block to your JSON parsing try/catch and post the error that is caught:

```
//parse json data
 try{
     JSONArray jarray = new JSONArray(result);
        for(int i=0 ; i<jarray.length() ; i++) {
        JSONObject ob = jarray.getJSONObject(i);
        String titulo = ob.getString("title");
        String cate = ob.getString("catid");
        int cat = Integer.parseInt(cate);
        String coord = ob.getString("extra_fields_search");

        String latitud = coord.substring(0, 9);
        Float lat_f = Float.parseFloat(latitud);
        int lat = lat_f *1000000;

        String longitud = coord.substring(10, 19);
        Float lon_f = Float.parseFloat(longitud);
        int lon = lon_f*1000000;

        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat, lon);
        negocioNuevo = new Negocio(titulo, cat, point);
        listaNegocios.add(negocioNuevo);
        }  
 }catch(JSONException e){
     Log.e("miError de JSON", "Error parsing JSON "+e.toString());
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("miError de General", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
 }
```

Comment: I get this error: E / MyError General (1205): Error parsing data java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "37.770783". Besides running this way and not leave the RuntimeException, but the program does not work as it should work.

Comment: So clearly your string has a decimal, so try parseFloat(), as I updated above. Multiplying it by 1000000 should allow you to store it as an int

Comment: parseFloat() doesnt work. I dont know why not work when i multiplying it by 1000000. Do i well?

Comment: Still not working, I think the problem is in the conversion of one data type to another

Answer (score 0):

In the connection class try to replace

```
public Conexion(OnTaskCompleted listener){
    this.listener=listener;
}
```

with

```
public void setOnResultsListener(OnTaskCompleted listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
```

and then replace in MainActivity:

```
Conexion conexion = new Conexion(this);
conexion.execute("tipo");
```

with:

```
Conexion conexion = new Conexion();
conexion.setOnResultsListener(this);
conexion.execute("tipo");
```